# Why Depth First Search checks vertices this way?

Tags: graph, depth-first-search

I'm learning graphs and have encountered such implementation of Depth First Search algorithm that finds cycles in a graph

Why should we check that `w !== u`. In which case can `w === u` ?

```
dfs(v, u) {
    this._marked[v] = true;

    const adj = this._graph.adj(v);

    for (const w of adj) {
        if (!this._marked[w]) {
            this.dfs(w, v);
        } else if (w !== u) {
            this.hasCycle = true;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your algorithm is for undirected graphs and `u` is the parent of `v`. When you call `this._graph.adj(v)` it returns all adjacent including the parent `u`. The Condition `w !== u` check whether you have visited a node twice, it means you have two different paths to the node from your root. This means a cycle. But in the case that `u` is the parent node you are counting the edge `E(u,v)` twice which is not a definition for a cycle.

Comment: But in which case can w === u be true? I see only when a vertex directs to itself

Comment: It's not directed to itself. `adj` contains all children of `v` and the parent `u`. So, when `w` is `u` since we have already just visited it, `!this._marked[w]` is False. But we can consider this as a cycle because it counts two paths _P(root, ..., u)_ and _P(root, ..., u, v, u)_ as two distinct paths which don't create a cycle.

Comment: Ohh, now I got it. Yeah, I made a stupid mistake. I forgot that if a vertex 1 is adjacent to 2 then 2 is adjacent to 1.  That is why it returns the parent and we need to that check at all. Thanks!